# What is the good and efficient way of Adapter implementation for multiple RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-recyclerview

In my app I have 4-5 RecyclerView with complex multiple row type, i used viewType to distinguished the view. For each of them I did create different adapter class and I used those adapter to respective RecyclerView and those working fine. But later on i tried using only one adapter class for all of my RecyclerView and that also work fine.

> What I wanna know that is it good to use one adapter class for many
>   RecyclerView? Or I should go back to previous way?

The way i used one adapter for all the RecyclerView is that. Suppose I have 4 RecyclerView and I used 4 adapter those, but later on with one adapter class I add an extra variable to as `adapterType` with adapter class constructor and also make data as `ArrayList<?>` which accept any type of data.
So after the adapter initialize I check `adapterType` and than create ViewHolder of that type and also for object calling I type cast the object by its respective data type which determined from `adapetType`.

**Below is my Adapter Constructor:**

```
    public ContestAdapter(List<?> list, Context context, int adapterType) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.adapterType = adapterType;
        try {
            listener = (ContestAdapterListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement ContestAdapterListener Interface");
        }
    }
```

**Below is my Adaper OnCreateViewHolder:**

```
@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
            @NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup,
            int i) {
        View view;
        switch (adapterType) {
            case QUIZ_FRAGMENT_FLAG:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.row_contest_quiz,
                                viewGroup, false);
                return new QuizViewHolder(view);
            case MY_FRAGMENT_FLAG:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.row_contest_points_history,
                                viewGroup, false);
                return new MyPointViewHolder(view);
            case WINNER_FRAGMENT_FLAG:
                if (i == VIEW_TYPE_TEXT) {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                            .inflate(R.layout.row_text,
                                    viewGroup, false);
                    return new TextViewHolder(view);
                } else {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                            .inflate(R.layout.row_contest_winner,
                                    viewGroup, false);
                    return new WinnerViewHolder(view);
                }
            default:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.row_contest_points,
                                viewGroup, false);
                return new PointsViewHolder(view);
        }
    }
```

> **This is how i combined my 4-5 RecyclerView Adapter Class with One Adapter Class but I don't know which option is good, to use separate
>   Adapter Class or to use One Adapter Class like my one?**

Answer (score 0):

check this library most be useful https://github.com/dipkastel/StickyRecycler

Comment: actually i'm not looking for a solution, i wanted to know the approached i used it efficient or not. Also your suggested link is using many different row type for one recycler view by one adapter but in my fact it's one adapter class for many recycler view with many different row type.

Comment: is completely depended to your structure is not about RecyclerView or adapters or any element else

Comment: you can get instance of adapter like new myadapter or use singletone like myadapter.getinstance or dependency injection  acturly when your items can repeat in recyclerviews is beter to have one adapter and when its difrent multiple adapters is beter cuse by less code ls beter